# Accessing a variable from a lower class that was NOT created as a child class (ie: using the "<" operator) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a ToDo list program I'm writing for practice. My problem is that by separating concerns and making each list be a class while each task is also a class, I would like to be able to call the name of the list which the new task is being added to without having to pass the list name into the task class (either upon creation or later):

```
class HigherClass

    def initialize
       @higher_class_variable = unique_value
       @instance_of_lower_class #keep variable empty for now
    end

end

class LowerClass

    def intitialize
        @lower_class_variable = unique_value #this should be the same unique value as above
    end

end

instance_of_higher_class = HigherClass.new
instance_of_higher_class.@instance_of_lower_class = LowerClass.new

instance_of_higher_class.@instance_of_lower_class.@lower_class_variable
#this should return the unique_value from the HigherClass instance
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access attributes:

```
attr_reader :lower_class_variable
```

Then you can just do this:

```
@instance_of_lower_class.lower_class_variable
```

Same principle applies here for higher class:

```
class HigherClass
  attr_writer :instance_of_lower_class
end
```

Then:

```
instance_of_higher_class.instance_of_lower_class = LowerClass.new
```

That all seems rather clunky considering you can do this:

```
class HigherClass
  attr_accessor :unique

  def initialize
    @unique = unique_value
  end
end

class LowerClass < HigherClass
  def initialize
    # Call superclass initialization
    super
    # Anything else you want here.
  end

  def something_using_unique
    call_method(unique)
  end
end
```